# Microsoft Authenticator Accounts Can They Be Shared?

Tags: security, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I am wondering if these scenarios are possible.

1. Have the same authenticator app on multiple phones. Say my bank has 2FA and I am using the authenticator app, can I have the "account" tied to 2 different phones?
2. Can I have the same account twice? Say both my wife and I both have 2FA on our bank (same bank different accounts) can we have both of them on the same authenticator app?

Answer (score 1):

> Have the same authenticator app on multiple phones. For example, say my bank has 2FA, and I am using the authenticator app. Can I have the "account" tied to 2 different phones?

This absolutely is possible.  I have the same TOTP authenticators on multiple personal computers (Authy and WinAuth) and across multiple phones (Android and iOS).

> Can I have the same account twice?

As long as you load the secret key for the specific authenticator, you can load the same authenticator to multiple Microsoft Accounts through the Microsoft Authenticator application. For example, I have loaded the same TOTP authenticator to (Authy, WinAuth, Google, Battle.net, Lastpass Authenticator, and Microsoft Authenticator).  **All I needed to do was provide the secret code each application.**  I have synchronized more than a dozen authenticators across every single device that I use.  Since 1Password supports TOTP, I have also synchronized them there.

> Say both my wife and I have 2FA on our bank (same bank, different accounts). Can we have both of them on the same authenticator app?

You would have to use a different TOTP authenticator, more than likely, unless the bank allows you to provide your own secret code instead of telling you what the secret code will be.  However, you could have synchronized your authenticators to any number of devices. That is the only reason I feel comfortable using them.

Answer (score 0):

I use accounts on two different computers and phones using the same credentials. 2FA is by text and I respond to the text on my phone for the account in question.

This works.

The only way my significant other could access the account is to have a password credentials. But then the other person would get the 2FA text on their phone and could access the account.

In my case we just use different account access to the same account (joint) and appear to the bank as different people.

Work carefully and you should be able to do as you wish. Be sure to use Text as 2FA and not fingerprints. Two people have different fingerprints and would require different access.

I tried the authenticator app once but found financial institution 2FA text authentications to be completely adequate. But if you use the Authenticator it can be used on two accounts. Refer also to my comments above about two people, but if they share credentials you can probably do this.